# How to resolve gcloud crashed (ReadTimeout): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloudfunctions.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=300)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I receive the error when triggering a cloud function using the gcloud command from terminal:

`gcloud functions call function_name`

On the cloud function log page no error is shown and the task is finished with no problem, however, after the task is finished this error shows up on the terminal.

`gcloud crashed (ReadTimeout): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloudfunctions.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=300)`

Note: my function time out is set to 540 second and it takes ~320 seconds to finish the job

Comment: I wonder whether the `gcloud functions call` timeout is static (300s)? Then, it wouldn't matter whether your deployed function has a longer timeout. Can you try `curl`'ing it instead?

Comment: Perhaps `curl --request GET --max-time 540 --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" $(gcloud functions describe ${NAME} --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")`

Comment: trying this ```curl --request GET --max-time 540 --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" $(gcloud functions describe XXX --project=XXX --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")``` produces ```curl: no URL specified!``` am i missing something in constructing the command? also in my original gcloud command I pass in --data argument, would i need to include that in curl as well?

Comment: You can run the embedded  `gcloud` commands separately to prove to yourself that they both produce sensible values. Yes, sorry, add `-d '{ ....}'` for any JSON data and use `--request POST` rather than `GET`

Comment: The first command (`gcloud auth ...`) gets an access token. The second command (`gcloud functions describe ...`) gets the Function's endpoint.

Comment: ```gcloud auth print-access-token```  produces reasonable result. ```gcloud functions describe ${NAME} --project=${PROJECT}``` does describe the function, but by adding ```--format="value(httpsTrigger.url)"``` the output becomes an empty line. 
```curl --request GET --max-time 540 --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" $(gcloud --project=XXX functions describe XXX)``` produces an output like:
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: availableMemoryMb
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
curl: (6) Could not resolve host:buildId ...

Comment: That's curious, it works for me. I thought I'd incorrectly written it down but I just checked it this morning. If you look at the result of `gcloud functions describe ...`, it should include the URL, something `https://something.cloudfunctions.com/something`. Use that URL in the `curl` command instead of `$(gcloud functions describe ...)`

Comment: I also tested a Cloud Function that I deployed with a `time.Sleep(400*time.Second)` (Golang) and the `gcloud functions call` times out for me too **but** the `curl` command succeeds without needing to set `--max-time`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that `gcloud functions call` times out after 300 seconds and is non-configurable for a longer timeout to match the Cloud Function.

I created a simple Golang Cloud Function:

```golang
func HelloFreddie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Sleeping")
    time.Sleep(400*time.Second)
    log.Println("Resuming")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello Freddie")
}
```

And deployed it:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy ${NAME} \
--region=${REGION} \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--entry-point="HelloFreddie" \
--runtime=go113 \
--source=${PWD} \
--timeout=520 \
--max-instances=1 \
--trigger-http \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then I `time`'d it using `gcloud functions call ${NAME} ...`

```sh
time \
  gcloud functions call ${NAME} \
  --region=${REGION} \
  --project=${PROJECT}
```

And this timed out:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ReadTimeout): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloudfunctions.googleapis.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=300)

real    5m1.079s
user    0m0.589s
sys     0m0.107s
```

> **NOTE** `5m1s` ~== 300s

But, using `curl`:

```sh
time \
  curl \
  --request GET \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  $(\
    gcloud functions describe ${NAME} \
    --region=${REGION}
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")
```

Yields:

```
Hello Freddie
real    6m43.048s
user    0m1.210s
sys     0m0.167s
```

> **NOTE** `6m43s` ~== `400s`

So, `gcloud functions call` times out after 300 seconds and this is non-configurable.

Submitted an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191071342) to Google's Issue Tracker.